# MySQL Using Stored Procedure: How to restrict decimal/allow whole numbers only?

Tags: mysql, heidisql

I made a stored procedure called `forDailyUpdates`, if I input ('-1', 'Type 1') for example, it will throw an error message which I have set in the code, if not, it will update the table.

My question is, is it possible to restrict decimal inputs also? Or any other method that if it has special character like dot (.) it will throw an error message. I am still open with any suggestions, thanks!

I am using heidiSQL, it doesn't have numeric data type.
Update: I tried many other functions such as truncate, substring, LIKE. It seems like SQL or HeidiSQL doesn't read (.) dot as a special character because it has its own function(it gives a list of suggestion whether database, table, keyword, function, etc.)

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `forDailyUpdates`;

DELIMITER $$

CREATE PROCEDURE `forDailyUpdates`(
IN `normaldays` INT,
IN `name` VARCHAR(50))

BEGIN
IF(normaldays < 0)
THEN
SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000'
SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'Please input a number that is not negative.';
ELSE
IF(normaldays > 5 ) // this should not allow decimal, just a dummy on 5  
THEN
SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000'
SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'Decimal';
ELSE
UPDATE months
SET
normal_days = normaldays
WHERE
active = TRUE and
is_task_type = TRUE and
task_name = name;
END IF;
END IF;
END$$
DELIMITER ;

CALL `forDailyUpdates`('-1','Acct 1');

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `forDailyUpdates`;
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of not allowing decimal, how about rounding its value as an integer:

> CAST(Round(normaldays, 0) AS INT)

You can also use `FLOOR()` or `CEIL()` function depending on your expectation.

Comment: Client says decimal should not be allowed on input. I also tried doing normaldays = 3.5 and normaldays = '3.5' it still goes through.

Comment: my answer is casting decimal i.e: 3.5 to 4 (as an integer) so that you don't have to check for every situation, but it depends on what you need my friend.

Comment: Where should I input the syntax for cast? I'm quite new to my task sorry

Comment: You should cast the input as soon as receiving it: normaldays = CAST(Round(normaldays, 0) AS INT)